# Byte/Dict to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

What is the best possible way to convert my data to DataFrame?

```
    data = b'{"word": "Gondwana", "date": "2019-03-27 13:07:12.404732"}'
           b'{"word": "alalus", "date": "2019-03-27 13:07:12.909517"}'
           b'{"word": "Balto-Slavonic", "date": "2019-03-27 13:07:14.911308"}'
           b'{"word": "peculatation", "date": "2019-03-27 13:07:15.421915"}'
```

I tried this. Didn't seem to work.

```
d = pd.DataFrame(dict(data))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `decode` values to `utf-8` and convert to dictionaries in list comprehension by `ast.literal_eval` or `json.loads`:

```
data = [b'{"word": "Gondwana", "date": "2019-03-27 13:07:12.404732"}',
        b'{"word": "alalus", "date": "2019-03-27 13:07:12.909517"}',
        b'{"word": "Balto-Slavonic", "date": "2019-03-27 13:07:14.911308"}',
        b'{"word": "peculatation", "date": "2019-03-27 13:07:15.421915"}']

import ast   

df = pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(x.decode("utf-8")) for x in data])
print (df)
                         date            word
0  2019-03-27 13:07:12.404732        Gondwana
1  2019-03-27 13:07:12.909517          alalus
2  2019-03-27 13:07:14.911308  Balto-Slavonic
3  2019-03-27 13:07:15.421915    peculatation
```

Alternative solution, should be faster in large data:

```
import json

df = pd.DataFrame([json.loads(x.decode("utf-8")) for x in data])
```

Comment: I have edited the data a bit. I guess it will still be the same, right? @jezrael

Comment: @Jazz - Values are in list? Then solution is simplier.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just construct a dictionary with a string of bytes formatted like a python dict. You'll need to parse it somehow.

If you know that your byte string is always going to be a valid dict. You can try

`dict(eval(b'{"word": "soning", "date": "2019-03-27 13:07:13.409948"}'))`

and you should be ok. If you don't know what will be in the byte string I would advise against the use of eval.

The other answer here advises use of `ast.literal_eval` this is safer than `eval` because `literal_eval` cannot be used to evaluate complex expression. 
see: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

you can get literal_eval from the ast module

```py
from ast import literal_eval
literal_eval(b'{"word": "soning", "date": "2019-03-27 13:07:13.409948"}')
```

Comment: [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)